# How to put QscrollArea into QGridLayout?

Tags: c++, qt

I have written a simple program where the dialog window opens in maximized mode and there are some labels and buttons set to this window. I set a gridlayout to my window and added the labels and buttons to the layout , and my code worked fine. When I try to use scrollarea instead of the pink label(which is in row=1 and column=1), I don't get the same result that I got from putting the pink label in (row=1 and column=1).
I know that when labels or buttons are supposed to be in a scrollarea, I must declare a widget and setwidget to the scrollarea, then declare a layout and setlayout to the widget. But for this case(that the scrollarea itself must be in a layout) I don't know what to do.

Here is the code:

dialog.h:

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QScrollArea>


namespace Ui {
 class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();
    QLabel *red_label;
    QLabel *pink_label;
    QLabel *yellow_label;
    QScrollArea *scrollArea;
    QPushButton *button_one;
    QPushButton * button_two;
    QPushButton * button_three;


private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
 };

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

dialog.cpp:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QWidget>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
  QDialog(parent),
  ui(new Ui::Dialog)
 {
    ui->setupUi(this);

  this->setWindowState(this->windowState() ^ Qt::WindowMaximized);
  this->setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint | 
  Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint);



  red_label = new QLabel(this);
  red_label->showFullScreen();
  red_label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignHCenter);
  red_label->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
  red_label->setObjectName("forlumha_Name");
  red_label->setStyleSheet(
  "QLabel#forlumha_Name {"
     "background-color:red;"
             "}"
             );

 /* pink_label = new QLabel(this);
  pink_label ->showFullScreen();
  pink_label ->setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignHCenter);
  pink_label ->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
  pink_label ->setObjectName("forlumha_Name");
  pink_label ->setStyleSheet(
  "QLabel#forlumha_Name {"
     "background-color:pink;"
             "}"
             );*/



yellow_label = new QLabel(this);
yellow_label->showFullScreen();
yellow_label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignHCenter);
yellow_label->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
yellow_label->setObjectName("forlumha_Name");
yellow_label->setStyleSheet(
"QLabel#forlumha_Name {"
    "background-color:yellow;"
            "}"
            );



button_one = new QPushButton(this);
button_one->setFixedSize(50,50);
button_two = new QPushButton(this);
button_two->setFixedSize(50,50);
button_three = new QPushButton(this);
button_three->setFixedSize(50,50);

//.......adding scrollarea........//
scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);


//..........set layouts......//

QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();
this->setLayout( layout );
layout->addWidget(red_label,0,0,15,1);
layout->addWidget(yellow_label,0,1,1,1);
//layout->addWidget(pink_label,1,1,14,1);
layout->addWidget(scrollArea,1,1,14,1);


layout->addWidget(button_one,6,2,1,1);
layout->addWidget(button_two,7,2,1,1);
layout->addWidget(button_three,8,2,1,1);


}

 Dialog::~Dialog()
{
   delete ui;
 }
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  Dialog w;
  w.show();

  return a.exec();
 }
```

The above code output :
[image]

When I comment the pink_label parts and declare a scrollArea and put it in row=1 and column=1,the output is :

[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's your question. If it is: "Why does the red label collapse if the pink label is replaced by a `QScrollArea`?" then the answer is simple: The red label seems to contain no text. So, it has only a minimal size requirement and the `QGridLayout` assigns most of the available width to the `QScrollArea`. Set a text into the red label and see how `QGridLayout` will consider this respectively.

Comment: @Scheff thank you for replying. Yes my problem is collapsing the red label. I set some text to it and it worked fine! Also, I set width to the red label and got the result.

Comment: Concerning _Also, I set width to the red label and got the result._: Please, note that the actual intention of the `QLayout` is to not to work with absolute sizes. Instead, it should consider current size requirements of individual cells to provide the best compromise. So, this is as independent as possible of screen size, windows size, font sizes, varying text sizes (due to localization), etc.